# Widgets are not displaying in the admin panel

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget

I am using WordPress, I have an issue with the widget. I am not getting the widget in the WordPress admin panel.

I am getting the error in the console

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: null has no properties
> /wp-includes/js/dist/edit-widgets.min.js?ver=7ac5bb27bb662c888b918bc66c0a0a65:2

Any idea how to solve this?

I have disabled my all the plugins but still getting the error in the console.

[image]

Comment: Are you find the solution for this issue. We also got this issue in wordpress from past few days.

Comment: @AnanthaselvamP, I have installed the classic widgets plugin and started working.